# How to make a <input type="number"> higher or equal than a number

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a form like this

```
<input type="text" id="theName">
<input type="number" id="theNumber">
<input type="button" id="submitForm">
```

So how to validate by AngularJs when the button is clicked.The inputs can't be empty and the number in #theNumber input to be equal or greater than 0.

Comment: I would imagine you can just use the `min` and `max` attributes within that input tag, or create a submit function in your controller to handle the logic.

And you can just add the `required` attribute to each of the inputs that are required, and angular should handle that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<form ng-controller="FormController as FormCtrl">
   <input type="text" required id="theName" ng-model="FormCtrl.name">
   <input type="number" required min="1" max="10" id="theNumber" ng-model="FormCtrl.number">
   <button type="submit" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
</form>
```